# How to get an Application object in a java shell process started using app_process?

Tags: android

On my Android device, I am launching a Java class via `app_process` so that my Java classes can run as a `shell` user. This approach is similar to the one described in [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/DEVELOP.md) where I use a command like

```
adb shell CLASSPATH=/data/local/tmp/classes.dex \
    app_process / my.package.MainClass
```

The classes launch just fine and work as expected. However, I also want to get an [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) object so that I can use some Android services like [`VPNService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService#prepare(android.content.Context)). I tried creating one by calling `new Application()` but it seems to just be a stub and throws `NullPointerException`.

The only hint I could find is to run the classes via the `activity manager` as [said here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/sEZ4lifLRuI/19F3lL4vg2UJ). But I could not figure out how to do that.

Thus, how can I launch my java classes running them as a `shell` user and get an `Application` object which can be passed to Android APIs?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about how to get the Application object (reference) in the Shell or in your app (Java code)?

Comment: In the Java code. But the Java code is not an Android app but pure Java code with a `public static void main` method similar to the [one in scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/genymobile/scrcpy/Server.java#L123). It is not started via usual app launching process but via the `app_process` command.